# How to query these values from two tables depending on criteria, using MS Access Design View

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to Access queries and SQL syntax and trying to build the following:

Given two tables A and B with fields x(key), y, z common to both tables and B.x being a subset of A.x, how would I generate a query that populates query.x from A.x, query.y from B.y, and query.z from B.z unless A.x values are unique to A, in which case query.y and query.z should come from A.y, and A.z, respectively.

Using Design View criteria I tried this (converted to SQL):

```
SELECT A.x
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.x = B.x
WHERE B.y = IIf( A.x Like 'T*', A.y, B.y ) 
      AND B.z = IIf( A.x Like 'T*', A.z, B.z )
```

I used `Like 'T*'` because the unique `x` values to `A` begin with `T` and I thought this might capture cases where there is a difference.

Comment: A.x values are unique to A, or unique to B?

Comment: @krishKM: unique to A, since A.x contains B.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether you can reconstruct the below query using the designer:

```
SELECT A.x, B.y, B.z
  FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.x = B.x
UNION
SELECT A.x, A.y, A.z
  FROM A WHERE x NOT IN ( SELECT x FROM B );
```

Comment: I could not reconstruct it in the designer but was able to apply the model in the SQL view. thx